# Data driven framework

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I have 10 test cases in Excel, if I run Selenium for each test case, one file should upload and write the result in same Excel. Does anyone know how to do that?
I know how to read Excel file, but for one test case one file upload I don't know how to do that.

```
File file =    new File(filePath+"\\"+fileName);
//Create an object of FileInputStream class to read excel file
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
Workbook guru99Workbook = null;
//Find the file extension by splitting file name in substring  and getting only extension name

String fileExtensionName = fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf("."));
```

Comment: Use this to read from an excel file https://gist.github.com/navchandar/0d9a49f54fa20ca1264d65cb77203057. Try to develop a minimum code necessary to demonstrate the problem and your expected output. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and provide a detailed explanation of the problem and any error if you are getting.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by File upload. Did you mean update of file content? Pls clarify.

Comment: Acutally my project is validation so i need to upload csv file and salesforce will validate and throw the details ,now my requirement is for that i need to put my test case in excel and if i want to run 5th test case means accordingly that 5th test case file should upload and display the error